# Regarding ISO 8583 request response communication in javascript

Tags: iso8583

I want to send request & receive response in JavaScript using ISO-8583 message format. Please share the steps how it will implement.
Thank you in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this as you would need to establish a raw TCP connection to the host. Most JavaScript browser implementations does not allow straight TCP connections.

The way we do it is to create a webservices wrapper around our ISO 8583 client.

Comment: thanks @Andre, but how will it be possible ? like to send iso 8583 request in JavaScript.? Please suggest.

Comment: Please read the answer carefully. It is not possible to do this.

Comment: Javascript doesn't need to be restricted to the browser. E.g. write a JavaScript program to generate the ISO8583 message and run that in an environment like node, deno or the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library I have written just for that - Nodejs though. [ISO 8583 Js](https://github.com/zemuldo/iso_8583).
There is an example of how to do message encoding, passing via TCP and decoding on the other side. See [Example](https://github.com/zemuldo/iso_8583/tree/main/example)